# How do you define the NDK installation that ndk-build uses?

Tags: android, macos, command-line, android-ndk, ndk-build

How do you define the NDK installation that ndk-build uses?  I used the r10e build for a good while, then updated my NDK and modified my $PATH to point to the new location, but when I build using the ndk-build command in Terminal it still uses the older android-ndk-r10e version.

I know this because I use the NDK_LOG=1 option when invoking ndk-build and it produces the following verbose information as it builds my project. Notice the references to "**/NDKDev/android-ndk-r10e**".  That's my old installation.

```
 ~/Documents/MyNDKProject-- $ ndk-build NDK_LOG=1
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_TAG=darwin-x86_64 
GNUMAKE=/Users/user1/Documents/NDKDev/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/make (NDK prebuilt)
Android NDK: NDK installation path auto-detected: '/Users/user1/Documents/NDKDev/android-ndk-r10e'
Android NDK: GNU Make version 3.81 detected
Android NDK: Host OS was auto-detected: darwin
Android NDK:  Host operating system detected: darwin
Android NDK: Host CPU was auto-detected: x86
Android NDK: HOST_TAG set to darwin-x86
Android NDK: Host tools prebuilt directory: /Users/user1/Documents/NDKDev/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin
Android NDK: Host 'echo' tool: echo
. . .
```

Also note that when I enter echo $PATH at the Terminal prompt it gives:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx
```

and where you see **/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle** is exactly where it used to refer to the android-ndk-r10e path, so I'm certain I've updated my PATH successfully.  So anyhow, IF the PATH environment variable is not what ndk-build uses to determine the NDK installation to use, what does it use, and how can I modify it so that it uses my new installation which is at:

```
/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle
```

Comment: What's the output of `which ndk-build`?

Comment: @Francesca -- Wow.  which ndk-build produced "/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle/ndk-build".  So why is the build output indicating my older version?

Comment: Looks like you figured out why by yourself :)

Comment: @Francesca -- Yes.  With indispensable help from you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.  The problem was that when the .bash_profile file is successfully sourced in a given Terminal session it does not have any effect on other instances of Terminal that are open.  I had two instances of Terminal open and because I hadn't closed the one with which I was calling ndk-build the changes to .bash_profile weren't being applied.